# How can I get optgroup label when select an option in vuejs?

Tags: vuejs2

I want to get country group name when select option. I've countries with several group like

```
<template>
    <select id="countries" v-model="country" @change="getCountryGroup($event)">
        <optgroup label="Asia">
            <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
            <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
            ...
            <option value="BD">Bangaldesh</option>
            ...
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Australia / Oceania">
            <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
            <option value="AU">Australia</option>
            <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Africa">
            <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
            <option value="AM">Angola</option>
            <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="South America">
            <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
            <option value="BO">Bolivia</option>
            <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="North America">
            <option value="US">United States</option>
            <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Europe">
            <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="AL">Albania</option>
            <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</template>
```

Suppose when I select `Bangladesh` then I want to get optgroup name `Asia`. Here is my vueJs method

```
getCountryGroup: function(event){
    console.log( event.target.getAttribute('label') );
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider pulling the countries out to a suitable data structure rather than hard-coding them all directly into the template. Once you've got data as data you don't need to jump through hoops trying to extract it from the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two steps

1. Get the selected index
2. Find the selected option
3. Select the parent element (optgroup) for the selected option
4. Finally, get the label (Country group)

```
getCountryGroup: function(event){

    // 1. Get the selected index
    const index = event.target.selectedIndex;

    // 2. Find the selected option
    const option = event.target.options[index];

    // 3. Select the parent element (optgroup) for the selected option
    const optgroup = option.parentElement;

    // 4. Finally, get the label (Country group)
    const countryGroup = optgroup.getAttribute('label');

    console.log(countryGroup);
}
```

Here is the demo https://codepen.io/maab16/pen/KKKpJba

Comment: After seeing a lot of awful methods, this is the most graceful way.